# Error In jqxcalender : Globalize is not defined

Tags: angular, jqwidget

I am using jqxcalender in my angular comonent and when tage loaded im getting this error Globalize is not defined in the console how can i solve this error

I have tried importing jqxcalender in code

```
<jqxCalendar [width]="'100%'" [height]="390" [titleHeight]="50" [columnHeaderHeight]="80" [enableHover]="false [dayNameFormat]="'firstLetter'" [firstDayOfWeek]="1" [showOtherMonthDays]="false"  #myCalendar ></jqxCalendar>




DetailComponent.html:20 ERROR ReferenceError: Globalize is not defined
    at c.<computed>._format (jqxcalendar.js:8)
    at c.<computed>.renderTitle (jqxcalendar.js:8)
    at c.<computed>._renderSingleCalendar (jqxcalendar.js:8)
    at c.<computed>.render (jqxcalendar.js:8)
    at c.<computed>.refresh (jqxcalendar.js:8)
    at Object.push../node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js.b.jqx.applyWidget (jqxcore.js:15)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jqxcore.js:15)
    at Function.each (jqxcore.js:8)
    at init.each (jqxcore.js:8)
    at init.b.fn.<computed> [as jqxCalendar] (jqxcore.js:15)
```

Comment: Please share your component ts code

Comment: ts file dosent contain any thing just used that in design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved just have to update the jqxwidget to current version